# Does it make sense to use Black Scholes greeks to attribute P/L given the Black Scholes assumptions don't hold?

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, greeks

I've seen some takes from experts in the industry (Benn Eifert for example) who say that we should treat Black Scholes as a translation mechanism for putting price into a more workable form (IV). They say that no one really uses Black Scholes as a "model" since clearly the assumptions are violated.

However, these same people use Black Scholes calculated greeks for understanding the risk of a portfolio of options and for P/L attribution. Vega, vanna, and volga are also sometimes added to account for the non-deterministic nature of implied volatility.

My question boils down to this: shouldn't our Black Scholes calculated greeks be incorrect measures of our risk since they're just partial derivatives of an equation that's based on false assumptions? For example, if our Black Scholes greeks say we earned 100k from delta, 50k from gamma, 50k from vega, etc. why should we believe this at all? Isn't it totally possible that our gain from gamma is completely different under a more "correct" formulation of the second derivative of price to spot? How can we say we aren't using black scholes as a model if we're using black scholes greeks?

To be clear I'm not asking about "how much of our price change does our taylor series with a few terms explain", but rather how do we know we're accurately capturing the dynamics of our option with our greeks if we know the equation they're derived from has an incomplete picture of the market.

Comment: I do not know the context of the statement (nor Benn Eifert to be honest) but Black Scholes is used everywhere. Maybe he meant the closed form solution which doesn't hold for equity options which are American but you can just solve the PDE and will end up with almost identical results to CRR (or LR). The same applies to the Greeks. You will need to get them from the PDE grid and not from the closed form  solution.

Comment: @Alex Thank you for your reply, here's a specific Twitter thread from Benn for some context on the statement: https://twitter.com/bennpeifert/status/1574900518253568000. Emanuel Derman has a similar take in his book on the vol smile. I have no doubt that BS is used widely, but rather that we clearly violate the assumptions yet still use BS greeks to look at risk. A more concrete example would be that you could construct positions that are flat gamma/delta/vega/vanna but still cost some theta due to the volga exposure. So we are using BS greeks to build an exposure that doesn't exist in BS.